# TFS 2013: transition rule for an item requiring to change the "AssignedTo" user

Tags: tfs

Is it possible to create a rule for a Task transition that would require to change the "AssignedTo" field? Does not matter to what user, just not to the same as it was before the transition. I have tried to add an "EMPTY" rule for the transition and a "REQUIRED" for the target state, but TFS denied to save such a combination stating that it is inconsistent.
Background: we have "In progress" and "In review" task states and it is required that review is done by another developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the NOTSAMEAS https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194953.aspx if you copy the original field value somewhere first so it can be compared with that rule.

Comment: Thank you, indeed it works! Kinda clumsy, but it does the trick :)